# How to use from Global Resources items in html tags

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm trying to design a website by ASP.NET Web Form. I know how to use Global Resources items in asp and C# , but I can not use from this items in html tags.

More details:

There is "SiteMap.resx" file which contain some items. For example:

(Name:AboutTitle & value:About Us) & (Name:Help & value:Help)

I want to put "AboutTitle" between" " in below code line.

```
<li id="liBlog" runat="server" class="navbar-item">
    <a href="#menu-about" class="navbar-item-target">
        {Here!}
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a

```
<asp:Literal ID='the_id' Text='Default text'/>
```

and the use a global resource to set the text.

or directly

```
<asp:Literal ID='the_id' Text='Default text' meta:resourcekey="textID"/>
```

Comment: do you mean: using sitemap values in your html code?

Comment: <asp:Literal ID="litBlog" runat="Server" class="navbar-item" 
Text="<%$Resources:SiteMap,AboutTitle%>" />
could you tell me how I can change this to html code ?

Comment: `<asp:Literal .... />` will be translated to `<span>The text<span/>`  in client html code, I'm sorry, but I can't understand what exactly do you need.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your example, what I believe you need is this:

```
<li id="liBlog" runat="server" class="navbar-item">
    <a href="#menu-about" class="navbar-item-target">
         <%=Resources.LangText.String0001%>
    </a>
</li>
```

**LangText** is the file name in your Resources and **String0001** is just a reference to that file.

Hope it helps